# How to change the property of a css class on click on a button?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, leaflet

I am trying to change the property of a CSS class on click on a button.
Firstly i have this button in my html

```
   <button id="Regions" active="false" 
class="btn-square orangee-border grow" 
data-target="#square1">Private Cloud Regions</button>
```

Then i have this css class where i want to change the property from display: none to display: block on click on the previous button!

```
.zone-marker {
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif !important;
    font-size: 10px !important;
position: absolute;
    width:auto;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  z-index: inherit !important;
display: none;
  }
```

I have try

```
document.querySelector('#Regions').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('.zone-marker').classList.add('myClass');
});
```

to apply the same class with just with a display block!

```
.zone-marker {
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif !important;
    font-size: 10px !important;
position: absolute;
    width:auto;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  z-index: inherit !important;
display: block;
  }
```

It doesn't work.. If anyone knows it would be great !

Comment: Please try to create a [mre]. Also state whether you're trying to actually change the *class rule* or just the visibility of an element: https://jsfiddle.net/2q9r7z1p/ Also note that you should probably use a 2nd class for the visibility, and add/remove it to hide/show the marker.

Comment: `myClass` != `.zone-marker` . please check the `add` Class name

Comment: You are using `'.zone-marker'` as querySelector, but your button doesn't have an `zone-marker` class.

Comment: @Derlin OP is trying to make a click on the button change some other element, one that does have the zone-marker class.

Comment: @ChrisG Exactly, i want to change the visibility of an element on click on the html button!

Comment: @Derlin .zone-marker is CSS properties of a marker on my leaflet map!

Comment: Best use this then: https://jsfiddle.net/f1ynLvtu/

Comment: As a general note, is good practise to make the style change on a class, and add or remove the class rather than control inline styles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could this be want you are trying todo.

```js
document.querySelector('#Regions').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('.zone-marker').style.display = "block";
});
```

```css
.zone-marker {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif !important;
  font-size: 10px !important;
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  z-index: inherit !important;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="Regions" active="false" class="btn-square orangee-border grow" data-target="#square1">Private Cloud Regions</button>
<div class="zone-marker">JUST A DIV</div>
```

Or you can toggle display from `none` to `block` with this.

```js
document.querySelector('#Regions').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const el = document.getElementsByClassName('zone-marker')[0];

  if (el.style.display === "block") {
    el.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    el.style.display = "block";
  }
});
```

```css
.zone-marker {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif !important;
  font-size: 10px !important;
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  z-index: inherit !important;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="Regions" active="false" class="btn-square orangee-border grow" data-target="#square1">Private Cloud Regions</button>
<div class="zone-marker">JUST A DIV</div>
```

If you have multiple elements with the same class `zone-marker` and want to toggle display from `none` to `block` on all of them you can try this below.

```js
document.querySelector('#Regions').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const el = document.getElementsByClassName('zone-marker');

  Array.from(el).forEach(el => {
    if (el.style.display === "block") {
      el.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      el.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.zone-marker {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif !important;
  font-size: 10px !important;
  width: auto;
  z-index: inherit !important;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="Regions" active="false" class="btn-square orangee-border grow" data-target="#square1">Private Cloud Regions</button>
<div class="zone-marker">JUST A DIV 1</div>
<div class="zone-marker">JUST A DIV 2</div>
<div class="zone-marker">JUST A DIV 3</div>
<div class="zone-marker">JUST A DIV 4</div>
<div class="zone-marker">JUST A DIV 5</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! It's partially works because i have many makers which use this CSS class and on click, it only display the first!

Comment: *I have many makers which use this CSS class and on click, it only display the first* - this is entirely relevant and you should make sure this information is in the question via an [edit].

Comment: Do you want them all to change?  Or just one "related" to the button?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a minimal JS fiddle example:
HTML:

```
 <button id="Regions" active="false" 
    class="btn-square orangee-border grow" 
    data-target="#square1"
    onclick="change()"
    >Private Cloud Regions</button>
```

js:

```
function change() {
document.getElementById('Regions').style.color = "red"
}
```

css:

```
.zone-marker {
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif !important;
    font-size: 10px !important;
position: absolute;
    width:auto;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  z-index: inherit !important;
display: none;
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j6f4vm5d/1/

Comment: You can use Stack Snippets (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar) to use an interface much like jsFiddle's to create a runnable snippet here on Stack Overflow so that no one has to go to another site to see the code work. It also has a Tidy button to take care of irregular indentation...